# How do I make a self repeating formula in Google sheets that

Tags: concatenation

How do I make a self repeating formula in Google sheets that CONCATENATES the content of 4 cells into 1? This one: `=ARRAYFORMULA( CONCATENATE( D3:H3 & ", " ))` works when copied manually, but I need it to repeat automatically when a new line is added?

Answer (score 0):

The CONCATENATE formula doesn't work in an array formula, the easiest way is to use the & operator instead.

=ARRAYFORMULA( D2:D & E2:E & F2:F &  G2:G & H2:H & ", " )

This will join whatever is in columns D, E, F, G and H; from row 2 to the end of the sheet.